# VBA Count Values in Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, count

I've read the post on this VBA problem, but my VBA script is still not working.

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim arrNames As Variant                     'Declare array named "arrNames"
arrNames = Sheet1.Range("F2:F1000")         'Array filled with column F
intN = Application.CountIf(arrNames, "*")   'does not work intent: count cells w/info
'intN = Application.CountA(arrNames)        'works but MsgBox displays value of 999
MsgBox (intN)

End Sub
```

How do I get the number of cells in my array containing any value?

***EDITED version after help***

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim arrNames As Variant                       'Declare array named "arrNames"
Dim i As Long

arrNames = Sheet1.Range("F2:F1000")           'Array filled with column F

For i = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)
    If (arrNames(i,1) = "") Then
        EmptyCounter = EmptyCounter + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't declared `Dim EmptyCounter As Long`

Comment: Can you not use the simplest approach like `MsgBox  Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("F2:F1000"))`??

Comment: @Greg, did my solution below help?

Comment: No and Yes. arrNames needs to be changed on Line 9 after the If statement as such: If arrNames(i,1) otherwise an error subscript out of range results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
intN = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F1000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
MsgBox intN
```

100% it works.

Comment: This does work, however I need "count" for an array as my arrays are manipulated in the script.

Comment: I'm nit sure I get you right on this one. But if I do you can try somthing like this: `intN = arrNames.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count` - I'm assuming that you had declared arrNames as Range before. Does that help?

Comment: What I meant was your answer really evaluates the values that will be placed into the array, not the array iteself. But there are times I will need to count the array after I have "sorted", removed duplicates etc from the array. In that case the intN = Worksheets... would not work.

Comment: ok, still not giving up on this one - you can re-define  your range in terms of rows like this: `Dim TheLastRow As Long
    TheLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F1000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    MsgBox (TheLastRow)` - that one finds the last non-empty row. then you can fire up the code I proposed in my first answer.

Comment: This makes sense and intN will give you an interger value. However how do I enter that last row value in setting the array range? The following does not work. arrNames = Sheet1.Range("F2":intN)

Comment: arrNames = Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(intN, 6))

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do it, as far as I understand. But you could run a simple loop to check if the values are equal to "" assuming string data.

For e.g.

```
For i = LBound(ArrayName) to UBound(ArrayName)
    If (ArrayName(i) = "") Then
        EmptyCounter = EmptyCounter + 1
    End If
Next i
```

If it's numeric or other type of data, you may try variations of the above loop using functions such as `IsEmpty(VariableName)` etc.

Comment: It usally just a string, e.g mixed data like S12-9

Comment: If (arrNames(i) = "") Then 'Script hangs on this line

Comment: what do you mean 'hangs'? What's the error that pops up?

Comment: Run Time Error '9':Subscript out of Range

Comment: That is very very odd, if it's going from LBound to Ubound, it's almost impossible for that. Is `i` declared as Long? or Integer? Please declare it as `Long` and see again.

Comment: variable "i" is declared as Long. The result is still the same. Run Time Error '9':Subscript out of Range

Comment: Please post your revised code in the question, it's difficult to read here.

Comment: See revised post above.